# spring batch restarting job with persistent storage job registry

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to use spring-batch in my spring boot application. I have a use case to stop the job during certain time duration in a day and once the time window passes, I want to restart the job from the suspended step. Till now, I have figured out that there are two ways of doing this as shown in below class:

```
class JobStarter {
  @Autowired protected JobLauncher jobLauncher
  @Autowired protected JobRegistry jobRegistry
  @Autowired protected JobOperator jobOperator
  @Autowired protected JobExplorer jobExplorer

  def startJob(Map config) {
    Job job = build(config, subject) // build the job programmatically
    JobParameters jobParameters = createJobParameters(subject, config) 
    jobLauncher.launch (job, jobParameters)
    jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceFactory(job))
  }

  def restartJob1(String jobName, JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobName)
    jobLauncher.launch (job, jobParameters)
  }

  // OR

  def restartJob2(String jobName) {
    def jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName, 0, 1)
    if (!jobInstances) {
      throw new Exception("Unable to find the job to restart")
    }
    def jobInstance = jobInstances[0]
    jobOperator.restart(jobInstance.instanceId)
  }
}
```

I have custom implementations of jobRepository and jobExplorer both backed by persistent storage.

**I can't use the default implementation of JobRegistry provided by spring batch as it is backed by in-memory Map and if the server goes down, the jobRegistry is empty so the restart of a suspended job fails. I am trying to implement JobRegistry but the problem is that I am having a hard time persisting the job factories within my custom implementation of jobRegistry:**

```
class PersistentJobRegistry implements JobRegistry {

  // Other methods and code omitted for brevity
  static ObjectMapper mapper
  static {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper() 
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping()
  }

  @Override
  void register(JobFactory jobFactory) throws DuplicateJobException {
    String jobFactoryStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(jobFactory)
    save(jobFactory.getJobName(), jobFactoryStr) // saves jobFactoryStr to store
  }

  @Override
  Job getJob(String name) throws NoSuchJobException {
    String jobFactoryStr = get(name) // gets a serialized factory from store
    JobFactory jobFactory = mapper.readValue(jobFactoryStr, JobFactory.class)
    return jobFactory.createJob()
  }
}
```

While saving, I get this as jobFactoryStr, which clearly won't work as there is just jobName and no other information about the job and its steps:

```
jobFactoryStr = {"jobName":"MyJob:f6892e89-4a76-4395-ba0a-ca82b477a407"}
```

I get below error in getJob() too:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobFactory
 at [Source: {"jobName":"Pipeline:api:testing:c3241e19-4f32-474f-90d2-2974b672c183"}; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:854)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._locateTypeId(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:93)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:58)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:132)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3066)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2161)
```

**I have two questions:**

1. Is my approach for restarting the job correct?
2. Is my approach for the jobRegistry implementation correct? What could be going wrong with above Jackson error?

Comment: Where is the `JobRegistry` bootstrapped from?

Comment: @Michael, it is injected by spring since a bean (which implements MapJobRegistry is present in the spring-batch jar). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I ask because you said that you can't use the Map based registry because if the server crashes it will be empty.  I'm assuming on restart the registry would be re-populated so the state would be restored without the need for persistence.

Comment: "I'm assuming on restart the registry would be re-populated so the state would be restored without the need for persistence. - "That is not what I am seeing in my environment.

Comment: Which goes back to my question as to where the `JobRegistry` is being bootstrapped from.  Who is populating it?  Are you using the `AutomaticJobRegistrar` or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

The built in Job Repository can be backed by any rdbms, you don't need to carve your own..  By default it is configured to point to an in-memory database, but it is a matter of changing configurations in a properties file.

Dig backwards through the spring context and properties files starting from the `job-repository` tag, throug hthe datasource definition.   Point the datasource at your target database.

The DDL for creating the tables for the most commonly used RDBMS' is embedded in the jar, and normally spring-batch will take care of creating the tables (in your DEV environment anyways) on the first launch of a spring-batch job.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html

Comment: I "need" to use redis instead of RDBMS. So that is the reason for custom implementation of JobRepository.